# Создание блока с нуля помощь

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте хотел спросить, как создать такой блок на html и css, чтобы картинка была в теге img, а не как background в css. За ранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

- Нужно картинку поместить в блочный элемент (например `div`)
- Установить блочному элементу ширину и высоту
- Установить картинке ширину и высоту равными `100%`, и задать ему радиус границы.

Можете попробовать что-то наподобие этого:

```css
div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyIAu.png"/>
</div>
```